# Changing Mailing Adress

Tags: debit-card

Do I have to wait 3-5 business days (how long it takes to update change of address) before I order a replacement debit card (I lost mine, and have recently moved but I just changed my address on my bank account)? Or can I go ahead and order it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you call them, you can make sure they'll use the new address, but if you want to do it online, there is some risk that the update is delayed.

Note also that an address change with an immediate request for a replacement debit card smells *very fishy* - this what a hacker / thief would do to get your money. Calling seems to be the better approach, as you can verify your identity further. Otherwise, you might well run into an automated block.